# Regex: Select string without Search/Replace

Tags: python, regex, python3

**I have many lines like this:**

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right font-14 color-blue mr-1"></i> Books To Read <span>30</span>
<i class="fa fa-angle-right font-14 color-blue mr-1"></i> Angels Heaven <span>11</span>
```

I want to select only the title from each line, ex. `Books To Read` and the number of each line, ex. `30`

I can do a regex formula:

**Find:** `<i class="fa fa-angle-right font-14 color-blue mr-1"></i>(.*? \w+ )<span>(\d+)</span>`

**Replace By:** `\1\2`

My problem: I want only to select those strings, not to replace them. So the search must highlight every string, without deleting anything with Replace. Is it possible? I want to use the regex formula into a Python code.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Python:**

```
import re

lines = '''
<i class="fa fa-angle-right font-14 color-blue mr-1"></i> Books To Read <span>30</span>
<i class="fa fa-angle-right font-14 color-blue mr-1"></i> Angels Heaven <span>11</span>
I want
'''

# Define the regex patterns
title_pattern = r'<i.*?>(.*?)<\/i>'
number_pattern = r'<span>(\d+)<\/span>'

# Extract the title and number using regex
titles = re.findall(title_pattern, lines)
numbers = re.findall(number_pattern, lines)

# Print the extracted titles and numbers
for title, number in zip(titles, numbers):
    print("Title:", title.strip())
    print("Number:", number)
    print()
```